# Adding custom form actions in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm using ActiveAdmin to add google OAuth credentials to a record. The client ID and Client Secret are added via `record/1/edit`, and I use those to generate a link to allow access. This link appears in `record/view`. I am trynig to find a way for the Administrator to enter the code returned by google oauth into the portal so that I can use it to generate credentials.

My current attempt looks something like this

`row "Code from Google OAuth" do
        form do |f|
          label "Google Auth Code:"
          input :code, :label => "Code", :hint => "Code returned by google auth"
          f.action :submit
        end`

I get an "undefined method: action" error form this code. Any ideas on how to return user input as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form` is an Arbre tag that maps directly to HTML, in which case `action` is an attribute, eg.

```
form(action: '/someroute', method: :patch) do ... end
```

If you want to embed a Rails or Formtastic form you would use `form_for` or `active_admin_form_for` respectively.